# How do I tell if the app is launched from a URL scheme or a normal launch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, x-callback-url

Basically, whenever the app launches or opens I have a check to see if there's a link on the clipboard, and if so I ask the user if he/she wants to add it.

However, I recently added the ability to use x-callback-urls to add URLs into the app. If they use an app like LaunchPad to open a URL in my app, the "do you want to add the URL from your clipboard?" notification still opens, which doesn't make much sense as they've already launched it to add that URL.

Problem is, the `openURL:` method in my AppDelegate is called to handle the URL scheme *after* `appDidFinishLaunching` and `appWillEnterForeground`, so I can't put a check in those to see if the `openURL` method was already called. I could use a `dispatch_after`, but that seems lazy and hacky.

Is there a way to check *how* the app was launched, i.e.: via a URL scheme or via a manual open?

Answer (score 9):

Don't implement `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`. Use `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` instead. Likewise don't use `application:handleOpenURL:`, use `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` instead.

If you are launched from a URL the options dictionary will contain a UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey key, and the value for that key will be the URL.

However, if your app is already running but is in the background and the user invokes a URL that re-opens your app, you will get a `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` message instead.
What you really need to do is implement a handleURL method, and then call that method from both `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`

### EDIT:

Note that in iOS 9, Apple deprecated `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` and added the new method `application:openURL:options:`.

If your app is iOS 9 and later only, you should implement the new `application:openURL:options:` method. If you need to support iOS 9 **and** earlier versions, you should probably implement both `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` and the new iOS 9 method `application:openURL:options:`. The OS will call the correct version for the OS version you are running. I would then create a common method that both of those call. That way you get called from both OS versions, but your code to handle opening an URL is only in one place.

Comment: View this answer to see how to reference `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` 
with Swift 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26649321/144088

Comment: Based on our testing, if the user launches from a URL, it seems like `application:openURL:options` gets called even if the app isn't already running.

Answer (score 1):

`applicationDidBecomeActive` is called after `openURL` and `continueUserActivity` (and after `appWillEnterForeground`), so is a good place to determine how the app was opened.

Cache the url in `openURL` and `continueUserActivity` (depending on the source, deep links may come from `continueUserActivity`. Anecdotally, I always see that method called when opening a link from Messages. Then check that url in `applicationDidBecomeActive`

```swift
  private var launchURL:URL?

  static func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    launchURL = userActivity.webpageURL
    // Do something with userActivity
    return true
  }

  static func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    launchURL = url
    // Do something with URL
    return true
  }

  static func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    defer {
      launchURL = nil // Just cleaning up
    }

    let didLaunchFromURL = launchURL != nil
  }
```

Comment: I see didBecomeActive being called before open url using breakpoints.

Comment: @Kevin, @Amber K: `didBecomeActive` may occur earlier than `continueUserActivity` in a case when application is already on the screen and scan NFC tag performed with URL on which application is reacted (via applinks technique)