# Read UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8

Simply want to read the launch options in Swift.

This is my old obj-C code which worked fine:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    NSURL *URL = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];  
    if (URL)
```

this is what I think the Swift code should look like:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    if let options = launchOptions
    {
        let URL: NSURL = options(UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey) as String
```

but it gives the error:

> '(NSString!) -> $T2' is not identical to '[NSObject : AnyObject]'

A casting error? but having difficulty casting it properly and can't find links for how to do it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Swift 3:**

In Swift 3, `launchOptions`is a dictionary of type `[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?`, so you'd access the value like this:

```
launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.url]
```

Since the key type is `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey`, you can abbreviate the `enum` type as simply `.url`:

```
launchOptions?[.url]
```

The value associated with that key is a `URL` though, and not a `String`.  Also, the key might not be present in the dictionary, so you should use conditional casting `as?` instead of normal casting.

In Swift, you want to do:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let url = launchOptions?[.url] as? URL {
        // If we get here, we know launchOptions is not nil, we know
        // key .url was in the launchOptions dictionary, and we know
        // that the type of the launchOptions was correctly identified
        // as URL.  At this point, url has the type URL and is ready to use.
    }
```

---

**Swift 2:**

In your code, `launchOptions` is a dictionary of type `[NSObject: AnyObject]?`, so you'd want to access the value like this:

```
options?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey]
```

The value associated with that key is an `NSURL` though, and not a `String`.  Also, the key might not be present in the dictionary, so you should use conditional casting `as?` instead of normal casting.

In Swift, you want to do:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    if let url = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] as? NSURL {
        // If we get here, we know launchOptions is not nil, we know
        // UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey was in the launchOptions
        // dictionary, and we know that the type of the launchOptions
        // was correctly identified as NSURL.  At this point, url has
        // the type NSURL and is ready to use.
    }
```

Comment: So no need to do:  
if (!URLString.isEmpty)
{
 //do some stuff
}
according to your comments?

Comment: You'll have a `NSURL` object.  You'll want to access parts of it.  For instance `if let path = NSURL.path { // path is a String`.

Comment: It's `launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.url]` for Swift 3

Comment: Thanks, @ArthurWang! I have updated the answer with Swift 3 syntax.